# Python[2.7] : ValueError: I/O operation on closed file

Tags: python, algorithm

I have searched similar problems in here and didn't find a solution to my problem. 
I am coding a network simulation that will schedule random generated packets. I am using NetworkX to create my graph. the simulation create packets randomly and find paths through min cut algorithm then schedule the packet in the queue then calculate the mean slowdown and mean delay and other statistics.
I think the problem resides at the algorithm function I wrote because during run after several simulation runs it stops with different error type. once its ValueError: I/O operation on closed file and another time it gives me KeyError:3 or KeyError:2 
I don't know where is the problem.

my code is really long but I'll attach it for better chance to find solution please put in mind that the errors always appear after some runs in the GraphMinCut function hopefully it would clarify the reason of these errors.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import networkx as nx
import random 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from operator import itemgetter
NewG=nx.Graph() #this is going to be a connected graph
num_node=5
num_edges=(num_node*(num_node-1))/2
RTrange=10 #release time range
FlowRange=3

nodelist=[]
for i in range(0,num_node):
    nodelist.append(i)

NewG.add_nodes_from(nodelist)
for i in range(0,num_node):
    for j in range(0,num_node):
        if i<>j:            
            if not NewG.has_edge(i,j) and not NewG.has_edge(j,i):
                NewG.add_edge(i,j,weight=1.0)

print (" the new graph have %d number of nodes and %d edges" % 
                         (NewG.number_of_nodes(),NewG.number_of_edges()))

pos=nx.spring_layout(NewG)  
colors=range(num_edges)
nx.draw(NewG,pos,node_color='#A0CBE2',edge_color='#A0BF11',width=4,
                                    edge_cmap=plt.cm.Blues,with_labels=True)
plt.savefig("edge_colormap.png") # save as png
plt.show() # display
runs=250
num_pack=10
# ------------begining of mincut function-------
def GraphMincut(G,source,sink,mylist,queue,t,removeEdge):
    pointer=queue.head

    addEdge=[]   

    if removeEdge:      # any previous unavalable edges need to be
                      #linked back as long as it hasn't been added to mylist
        for x in removeEdge:
            a=x[0]
            b=x[1]
            if (a,b) not in mylist and (b,a) not in mylist:
                if not G.has_edge(a,b):
                    e=(a,b)
                    addEdge.append(e)

    while removeEdge:
        removeEdge.pop()

    while pointer.time<t and pointer.next<>None:
        pointer=pointer.next

    if pointer.time==t:
        if pointer.data:
            for x in pointer.data:
                removeEdge.append(x)

    if addEdge:
        for x in addEdge:
            if not G.has_edge(x[0],x[1]):
                G.add_edge(x[0],x[1],weight=1.0)

    if removeEdge:
        G.remove_edges_from(removeEdge)           
    print "source and sink",source,sink  
    if nx.edge_connectivity(G,source,sink)==0:
        return mylist
    else: 
        MyEdgeList=[]
        MyNodeList=[]
        MyEdgeList=sorted(nx.minimum_edge_cut(G,source,sink))
        MyNodeList=nx.minimum_node_cut(G,source,sink)
        print("edge list:",str(MyEdgeList))
        print("node list:",str(MyNodeList))
        temp=[]       
        for j in MyEdgeList:
            print"j weight:",G[j[0]][j[1]]['weight']
            temp.append(G[j[0]][j[1]]['weight'])
        v=min(temp)    
        print "v:",v

        new_sink=None
        new_source=None
        for j in MyEdgeList:
            print "J:",j
            print"weight:",G[j[0]][j[1]]['weight']
            if v==G[j[0]][j[1]]['weight']:
                if j[0] in MyNodeList or j[1] in MyNodeList or (source in (j[0],j[1]) and sink in (j[0],j[1])):
                    print"j in if 1",j
                    if (source in (j[0],j[1])) or (sink in (j[0],j[1])):
                        mylist.append((j[0],j[1]))
                        break
                    else:
                        print("j[1]newsourec",j[1])
                        print("j[0]newsink",j[0])
                        new_source=j[1]
                        new_sink=j[0]
                        mylist.append((j[0],j[1]))
                        G.remove_edges_from(MyEdgeList)
                        mylist=GraphMincut(G,new_source,sink,mylist,queue,
                                                           t+1,removeEdge)
                        mylist=GraphMincut(G,source,new_sink,mylist,queue,
                                                           t+1,removeEdge)              

        if source in (j[0],j[1]) and sink in (j[0],j[1]):
            return mylist

        for i in MyNodeList:
            print"i ",i
            print"j[0]j[1]",(j[0],j[1])
            if i in (j[0],j[1]):
                if source in (j[0],j[1]):
                    new_source=i
                    new_sink=sink
                    break
                else: 
                    new_sink=i
                    new_source=source
                    break

        G.remove_edges_from(MyEdgeList)
        print"before call --new source and sink:",new_source,new_sink
        mylist=GraphMincut(G,new_source,new_sink,mylist,queue,t+1,removeEdge)

        return mylist

# ------------------end mincut function------------------
#-------------------packet generator -------------------

def GeneratePacket(source):
    Packet={}    
    Packet['source']=source
    sink_choice=nodelist
    sink_choice.remove(source)
    Packet['sink']= random.choice(sink_choice)
    nodelist.append(source)
    nodelist.sort()
    Packet['weight']=1.0         #random.randrange(2,10)
    Packet['computation_time_MC']=0 #initialized Time To Serve variable    
    Packet['MC_path']=[]
    Packet['release_time']=random.randrange(0,RTrange)
    Packet['rescheduledTime']=0 # to count the number of times it was 
                       #rescheduled due to unavailable edge at release time
    Packet['flow']=random.randrange(1,FlowRange)
    return Packet

#-------------------End packet generator -----------------
def Rearrange_Path(path,s):
    newpath=[]
    length=path.__len__()
    for i in range(0,length):
        temp=s

        for (a,b) in path:
            if temp == a:
                s=b
                newpath.append((a,b))
                path.remove((a,b))
            else:
                if temp==b:
                    s=a              
                    newpath.append((b,a))
                    path.remove((a,b))
    return newpath
# ------------------ Print packet details -----------------

def ShowPacket(Packet,i):
    print "Packet %d has :" %i
    print "source :",Packet['source'], "destination :", Packet['sink']
    print "release time =  :",Packet['release_time']
    print "number of flows =",Packet['flow']
    print "MC path :",Packet['MC_path']
    print "computation time is :",Packet['computation_time_MC']

    print "-"*20

# ------------------ End procedure ---------------    

# ------------------list classes   -----------
class Node(object):

    def __init__(self, prev, next):
        self.data = []
        self.prev = prev
        self.next = next
        self.time=0
        self.packetID=[]

class DoubleList(object):

    head = None
    tail = None

    def __init__(self):
        self.head=None

    def size(self):
        current = self.head
        count = 0
        while current != None:
            count = count + 1
            current = current.next

        return count

    def append_newNode(self, data,position):
        new_node = Node( None, None)
        if self.head is None:
            self.head = self.tail = new_node
            new_node.data.append(data)
            new_node.time=position   
        else:
            new_node.prev = self.tail
            new_node.next = None
            self.tail.next = new_node
            self.tail = new_node
            new_node.time=position
            new_node.data.append(data)

    def append_packet(self, pID,Rtime):
        new_node = Node( None, None)
        if self.head is None:
            self.head = self.tail = new_node
            new_node.packetID.append(pID)
            new_node.time=Rtime

        else:
            new_node.prev = self.tail
            new_node.next = None
            self.tail.next = new_node
            self.tail = new_node
            new_node.packetID.append(pID)
            new_node.time=Rtime

    def append_MiddleNode(self,pID,edge,Rtime,top,bottom):
        new_node = Node( None, None)
        new_node.prev=top
        new_node.next=bottom
        top.next=new_node
        bottom.prev=new_node 
        if edge: 
            new_node.data.append(edge)
        new_node.time=Rtime
        if pID:
            new_node.packetID.append(pID)

    def show_all(self):
        current_node=self.head
        print "Show all scheduled items in event queue :"
        while current_node is not None:
            print current_node.time , current_node.packetID,  
                                                  str(current_node.data)  
            current_node = current_node.next
        print "*"*50

# ------------------begin simulation  ------------- 
with open ("resultFile.csv","w") as RF:
    RF.write(str(date))
    RF.write("\n ")   
    RF.write("run#,Mean WT MC,Mean WT SPF,Mean SlowD MC, Mean SlowD SPF, Mean THr MC,Mean THr SPF")
    RF.write("\n")                


with open ("Result.csv","w") as DF: #contains detailed results
    DF.write(str(date))
    DF.write("\n")
    DF.write("run#,original RT, Rescheduled T, current RT, source, sink")
    DF.write(",Computation T,#of flows, Start, Finish,Wait \n")


for r in range(0,runs): #simulation run r times         
    with open ("resultFile.csv","a") as RF:
        with open ("Result.csv","a") as DF: #contains detailed results

            Packets=[] 
            for i in range(0,num_pack):#create random packets for the whole            
                                       # network 
                Packets.append({})
                packet_Source=random.randrange(0,num_node)
                Packets[i]=GeneratePacket(packet_Source)
                ShowPacket(Packets[i],i)
            # sort packets minimum release time first
            Packets.sort(key=itemgetter('release_time'))

            print "Packets after sorting by earlist release time -----"
            for i in range(0,num_pack):
                ShowPacket(Packets[i],i)
            # ----- create queue event for (MC)-------
            EventQueue = DoubleList()
            # initilize statistics parameters
            Mean_wait_t_MC=0            
            Mean_slowdown_MC=0
            Mean_Throughput_MC=0
            MC_delay_rate=0
            MCThroughput=0
            MC_slowdown=0    

        #---inser packets in order in my eventQueue for MC ------------
            for i in range(0,num_pack):
                R=int(Packets[i]['release_time'])
                if EventQueue.size()==0:
                    EventQueue.append_packet(i,R)
                    EventQueue.show_all()
                else:
                    current=EventQueue.head
                    appended= False
                    for n in range(0,EventQueue.size()):
                        if current.time==R:
                            current.packetID.append(i)
                            EventQueue.show_all()
                            appended= True
                            break
                        else:
                            current=current.next
                    if appended==False:
                        EventQueue.append_packet(i,R)
                        EventQueue.show_all()

                # ---------------------------------
            current_Packet=[]
            Time_pointer=EventQueue.head
            counter=num_pack

            while (counter > 0):
                if not current_Packet:    
                    while not Time_pointer.packetID and  Time_pointer.next<>None:
                        Time_pointer=Time_pointer.next
                    current_Packet=Time_pointer.packetID 

                while current_Packet:  
                    myGraph=nx.Graph()
                    print"mygraph..initialized"
                    nx.draw(myGraph)
                    plt.show(myGraph)
                    myGraph=NewG.copy() 
                    print"mygraph..after copy"
                    nx.draw(myGraph)
                    plt.show(myGraph)
                    packet_path=[]        
                    x=int(Packets[current_Packet[0]]['source'])
                    y=int(Packets[current_Packet[0]]['sink'])
                    ReleaseT=int(Packets[current_Packet[0]]['release_time'])
                    removeEdge=[]           
                    # here we get the path from Mincut function 
                    GraphMincut(myGraph,x,y,packet_path,EventQueue,ReleaseT,removeEdge)
                    packet_path=Rearrange_Path(packet_path,x)
                    p=current_Packet[0]
# incase the packet path was empty list due to unavailable edges at this time
# reschedule the flow by delaying it one time unit
                    if not packet_path:        
                        print "no available edges at this time release.. delay one time unit"
                        Packets[p]['release_time']+=1
                        print "p=",p
                        R=int(Packets[p]['release_time'])
                        Packets[p]['rescheduledTime']+=1
                        current=EventQueue.head
                        appended= False
                        for n in range(0,EventQueue.size()):
                            if current.time==R:
                                current.packetID.append(p)
                                current.packetID.sort()                    
                                current_Packet.remove(p)
                                EventQueue.show_all()
                                appended= True
                                break
                            else:
                                if current.time<R and current.next<> None:
                                    current=current.next
                                if current.time>R:
                                    EventQueue.append_MiddleNode(p,[],R,current.prev,current)
                                    current_Packet.remove(p)                        
                                    EventQueue.show_all()
                                    appended= True
                                    break
                        if appended==False:
                            EventQueue.append_packet(p,R)
                            EventQueue.show_all()
                            current_Packet.remove(p)
                        break
                    length= packet_path.__len__()   
                    print"path:",packet_path
                    print"length: ",length
                    flow=int(Packets[p]['flow'])            
                    Packets[p]['computation_time_MC']=length+flow-1
                    Packets[p]['MC_path']=packet_path
                    original_RT=ReleaseT-int(Packets[p]['rescheduledTime'])              
                    DF.write(" %s," %str(r))
                    DF.write(" %s," %str(original_RT))
                    DF.write(" %s," %str(Packets[p]['rescheduledTime']))
                    DF.write(" %s," %str(Packets[p]['release_time']))
                    DF.write(" %s," %str(Packets[current_Packet[0]] ['source']))
                    DF.write(" %s," %str(Packets[current_Packet[0]]['sink']))
                    DF.write(" %s," %str(length)) 
                    DF.write(" %s," %str(flow))
                    #initilize time variables for MC
                    Finish_time=0
                    Start_time=ReleaseT #just to make sure it doesn't start      
                                        # b4 it is released
                    current=EventQueue.head
                    start= False
                    counter -=1
                    end=False
                    while current.time <Time_pointer.time:
                        current=current.next
                    #----begin scheduling events for MC path --------  
                    for i in range(0,flow): # loop to schedule every flow
                        position=ReleaseT +i
                        if current.time<>position:
                            current=EventQueue.head
                            while current.time <position and current.next<>None:
                                current=current.next
                        for j in packet_path:
                            for k in range(0,EventQueue.size()):
                                if position==current.time:
                                    a=j[0]
                                    b=j[1]
                                    if (a,b) not in current.data and (b,a)not in current.data:
                                        current.data.append(j)
                                        EventQueue.show_all()
                                        position+=1                
                                        if start==False:
                                            start=True
                                            Start_time=current.time
                                            DF.write(" %s,",%str(Start_time)) 
                                        if current.next <> None:                        
                                            current=current.next
                                        else:
                                            end=True
                                        break
                                    else:
                                        if current.next==None:
                                            position+=1
                                            EventQueue.append_newNode(j,position)
                                            current=current.next
                                            end=True
                                            break
                                        current=current.next
                                        position+=1        
                                else:
                                    if (position<current.time):
                                        EventQueue.append_MiddleNode([],j,position,current.prev,current)
                                        EventQueue.show_all()
                                        position+=1                
                                        if start==False:
                                            start=True
                                            Start_time=current.time
                                            DF.write(" %s,",%str(Start_time))
                                        break
                                    if (position >current.time):
                                        EventQueue.append_newNode(j,position)
                                        EventQueue.show_all()
                                        position+=1            
                                        if start==False:
                                            start=True
                                            Start_time=current.time
                                            DF.write(" %s,"          %str(Start_time))
                                        current=current.next  
                                        end=True
                                        break
                    if end==False:
                        current=current.prev

                    Calculate_TT= length + flow -1 # Calculate travel time 
                               #is used to measure travel time between nodes
                    print "current time is=",current.time
                    Finish_time=current.time+1
                    MCThroughput =MCThroughput + (Finish_time - original_RT)
                    Wait= (Finish_time - original_RT - Calculate_TT)   
                    MC_delay_rate= MC_delay_rate+ Wait            
                    MC_slowdown= MC_slowdown + ((Finish_time -  
                                                  original_RT)/Calculate_TT)
                    DF.write(" %s," %str(Finish_time))
                    DF.write(" %s" %str(Wait))
                    DF.write("\n  ")
                    print " Start time is ", Start_time            
                    print "Finish time is", Finish_time
                    print "Computation time is ", Calculate_TT
                    print " wait time is ",Wait
       # now we need to put back the time of release and reschedule to their 
       #original state to be used again by SPF scheduling (later step)
                    Packets[p]['rescheduledTime']=0
                    Packets[p]['release_time']=original_RT
                    current_Packet.remove(current_Packet[0])
                    if not Time_pointer.packetID:
                        for g in range(0,EventQueue.size()):
                            if not Time_pointer.packetID and  
                                                    Time_pointer.next<>None:
                                Time_pointer=Time_pointer.next
                            else:
                                break

           #------------end scheduling events for MC path

            Mean_wait_t_MC= float(MC_delay_rate)/ num_pack
            Mean_slowdown_MC= float(MC_slowdown)/num_pack
            Mean_Throughput_MC= float(MCThroughput) / num_pack
            RF.write(" %s," %str(r))
            RF.write(" %s," %str(Mean_wait_t_MC))
            RF.write(" %s," %str(Mean_slowdown_MC))
            RF.write(" %s," %str(Mean_Throughput_MC) )
            RF.write("\n")                
            del EventQueue
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.

Comment: I have edited the code to be minimal as possible and complete

Comment: it seems the problem is at this line: print"weight:",G[j[0]][j[1]]['weight']
            if v==G[j[0]][j[1]]['weight']: I think its trying to access weight when it does not exist but I don't know why it doesn't exist I add the weight in a line before that.. can anyone help me please

Comment: The code doesn't run.  The **print** syntax suggests Python 3, but you've done comparisons with **<>** instead of **!=**.  I tried Python 2, but that gets invalid indentation on a print at line 256.  When I fix that with a continuation (back-slash), then I get the invalid syntax for the DF.write operation at line 428.  Finally, this code won't run because it still depends on data stored on your local computer.

Comment: @Prune the program does not require any data from my local computer it is all generated by the code

Comment: Ah ... sorry; I misread the file modes.

Answer (score 0):

I just want to tell you I found the problem is with anaconda not with my code because I run it in PyChrome and it worked so i think its the streaming library in anaconda